# Ubuntu Screencasting: Libavdevice segmentation fault

Tags: ffmpeg, xorg, libav, x264

I'm trying to stream to twitch a screencast of a remote desktop, but I meet some segmentation fault.

The OS is: Xubuntu 14.04 , xfce, x2go

I tried with Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 12.04, ffmpeg and avconv, without success.

The command I try is:

```
desktop@beta:~/Desktop$ echo $DISPLAY
    :50.0

desktop@beta:~/Desktop$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 800x600 -i :50.0 -vcodec libx264 -vpre lossless_ultrafast -threads 0 video.mkv
    ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
      configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
      libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
      libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
      libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
      libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
      libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
      libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
      libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
      libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
    [x11grab @ 0x1423600] device: :50.0 -> display: :50.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 800 height: 600
    [x11grab @ 0x1423600] shared memory extension found
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
desktop@beta:~/Desktop$
```

The core file is just a mess of characters, while I found this message in /var/log/syslog

```
Jul  3 11:36:30 beta kernel: [ 2382.305251] ffmpeg[29220]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fc3cb0e1008 sp 00007fff0a248a30 error 4 in libavdevice.so.53.5.103[7fc3cb0d3000+12000]
```

Is this because I'm using x2go? I can install another OS, but I need x2go

Comment: I tested with a fresh install of arch linux and it still doesnt work... I'm starting to think this is because I'm using x2go without a real monitor, is this possible?

Comment: Does "doesn't work" mean that the `ffmpeg` in Arch is giving the same error message?

Comment: Yes same error. I found that the problem is the x2go display. I need to connect a REAL display to make it work. Is there a workaround?